# How can I block a group chat in Whatsapp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, contact-groups

I want to block a group chat from my Whatsapp, but I have no option on my Samsung Galaxy S5. Does anyone have any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, WhatsApp doesn't allow you to block a group per se. You can however, exit the group. And/or mute it.

To exit the group, click on the conversation header to show "Group info", then `Exit Group`

Answer (score 2):

You can block this through, First of all Save Admin number in contact, then Block that Admin through whats app then go to the whats app and exit the group, he will never add you again.

Comment: But why? I don't want to save someone (unknown) number to my mobile. Some unknown number  is adding continuously me to there WhatsApp group :-( please help me...